# Automatic variables in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a lot of custom CMake commands, so I end up with a lot of repetition of this pattern in build scripts, e.g.

```
set(PREREQ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.txt ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar.txt)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT baz.txt
    COMMAND cat ${PREREQ} > baz.txt
    DEPENDS ${PREREQ}
)
add_custom_target(a ALL DEPENDS baz.txt)
```

Are there equivalents of GNU Make automatic variables in CMake (`$@`, `$<`, etc) so I can avoid specifying inputs/outputs twice (dependencies, output, and command)?

How else can I DRY it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using custom functions? For your example script this could look like this:

```
function (add_custom_command_with_target _targetName _output)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${_output}
        COMMAND cat ${ARGN} > ${_output}
        DEPENDS ${ARGN}
    )
    add_custom_target(${_targetName} ALL DEPENDS ${_output})
endfunction()
```

The function can be invoked in the following way:

```
add_custom_command_with_target(a baz.txt ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.txt ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar.txt)
```

In the function body you can use the predefined variable `ARGN`, which holds the list of arguments past the last expected argument. This is the closest thing you can get to GNU Make's predefined variables.